# Using literals in Switch statements rather than variables? Java

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, literals

What role do literals play in switch statements? Would it be better to use variables instead? Or how about using constants?

Comment: Within a `case` statement (in a `switch`) your labels must be compile time constants.

Comment: Avoid switch statements at all. Their static structure makes it unnecessarily anoying to maintain them. Try to find a dynamic way for your problem. (Just a general advice, not a solution to your question ;)).

Comment: @Tom I disagree, switch statements can be very useful in code and make code look much cleaner than adding many if statements.

Comment: Don't over use switch when you can use inhertance for example.  Using switch in the right place can be more efficient and cleaner (esp if you don't expect to change it too often)

Comment: @mdewitt If you think that if/else blocks are suitable substitutes for switch blocks, then you totally misunderstood my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you `switch` on a variable, never a literal.  You use `case` on a literal, like this:

```
public void doSomething(int x) { 
    switch(x) { 
        case 1:  System.out.println("It's 1."); break;
        default:  System.out.println("It's something else."); break;
    }
}
```

Using "switch" on a literal wouldn't really make much sense - a literal can only have one value (whose value is known at the time you write the code).   The switch block lets you do different things depending on what that value is.  But since you know what the value is (it's a literal) it wouldn't make sense to `switch` on a literal.

Constants often make an appearance in the `case` statement, but again not in `switch` for the same reasons literals aren't used there.